# Collect Database-Query asynchronously with futures

Tags: r, future, dbi, dbplyr

I am trying to asynchornize my dbplyrs queries, but currently it is not working:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(DBI)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), path = ":memory:")
db_flights <- copy_to(con, nycflights13::flights)

db_flights

flights_10000_df %<-% {
  db_flights %>% 
    head(10000) %>% 
    dplyr::collect()
}
#> Error in UseMethod("collect") : 
#> nicht anwendbare Methode für 'collect' auf Objekt der Klasse "list" angewendet
```

What is the problem here? (sorry for the german error)

(plan to improve the question later)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `dbConnect` 'con' can't be passed to a future. It is specific to the original R process that called it.

If you want to pull data asynchronously, each future would have to establish it's own database connection and use it's own connection to pull the data.

In your example,  it's creating a temporary database in memory each time a connection is called, but with a real database, you could establish a connection and download the table, but in this case, the future creates a new database in memory, and obviously the nycflights table isn't there.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(DBI)
library(nycflights13)
library(future)

plan(multisession)

con_settings<- list(RSQLite::SQLite(), 
                    path = ":memory:")


con<- do.call(dbConnect, con_settings)

nycf<-nycflights13::flights

db_flights <- copy_to(con, nycf)
dbListTables(con)

db_flights

flights_10000_df %<-% {
  future_con<- do.call(dbConnect, con_settings)
   #return the list of tables to show that the in-memory example doesn't work correctly for this example
   dbListTables(future_con)

#below would work with a real database
#  tbl(future_con, "db_flights") %>%
#    head(1000) %>%
#    collect 

}

flights_10000_df
```